# how to manipulate a 2D array

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I need to create a program that shows the user a menu, ask for the user to add an item to it, and then display the new menu.  I have to use a 2D array for this, and I am not allowed to use a function or an object.  This is what I have so far

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim arr1(3, 2) As String

        arr1(0, 0) = "Kebab"
        arr1(0, 1) = "9.99"
        arr1(0, 2) = "5"
        arr1(1, 0) = "Beef"
        arr1(1, 1) = "6.99"
        arr1(1, 2) = "7"
        arr1(2, 0) = "Chicken"
        arr1(2, 1) = "4.00"
        arr1(2, 2) = "9"
        arr1(3, 0) = "Beer"
        arr1(3, 1) = "0.99"
        arr1(3, 2) = "10"

        Console.WriteLine("Menu: ")
        Console.WriteLine("Kebab    9.99    5")
        Console.WriteLine("Beef     6.99    7")
        Console.WriteLine("Chicken  4.00    9")
        Console.WriteLine("Beer     0.99    10")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a new item")

        For i As Integer = 0 To arr1.Length - 1
            arr1(i, i) = Console.ReadLine()
        Next

        Console.Read()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: "Print the menu" probably means to print the array contents rather than hardcode it.  And if you *-**know*** you have to add an item to that array, make it one larger so you have some place to store the new info.  Then ask a specific question after you take the welcome [Tour]

Comment: I am supposed to hard code the initial menu, then I believe I am to redim the array to change its size.  I really do not understand how I am supposed to take the user entries and put them into my existing array.

Comment: Think about it - after you add an item, how are you going to know what to print?  Almost certainly, you are supposed to write a method to print the array and just use it twice - once before and after.

Comment: I'm sorry but are those real requirements? You are severely limited if so. It would be much easier to define a class / struct and have a List of them.

Comment: They are requirements from my teacher, yes.

Comment: "show the user a menu" does not imply hardcoding it at all.  Since  **[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)** is a key concept in software engineering, a method to print the array as a menu makes much, much more sense. You still havent told us what the problem is.  Have you gone to MSDN to read what `Console.ReadLine()` does and how to use it?

Comment: The line arr1(i, i) throws an error because your array has different size (3, 2).